# Trying to compare element of sublist

Tags: python

I am trying to check if the particular element of list inside list are equal or not:
I am having list inside list and in that I want to check the 3 element i.e at index 2 of the every sublist are equal or not.
Here is my code i have tried:

```
a = [['File1', 0, ' Message to check whether all this are same or not'], ['File1', 1, ' Message to check whether all this are same or not'], ['File1', 2, ' Message to check whether all this are same or not'], ['File1', 3, ' Message to check whether all this are same or not'], ['File1', 4, ' Message to check whether all this are same or not']]

for index,word1 in enumerate(a):
        for index2,word2 in enumerate(a):
            if index!=index2:
                if index[2] == index2[2]:
                    print(True)
```

When I run the above code I got the `TypeError`:

```
if index[2] == index2[2]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Please help me to sort out my problem

I want `True` If the 3rd element of all sublist are equal

Comment: You want `if word1[2] == word2[2]:`.  Remember that Python starts counting at 0.

Comment: doing `index, word in enumerate(a)` is leads to `index` being an integer. Doing `index[3]` is trying to subscript the integer which python doesn't allow. Perhaps you meant to do `word1[3] == word2[3]`? There are other issues with the code, for example even `word1[3]` is out of index since the largest index is `2`.

Comment: Sorry my mistake but it still gives the same error

Comment: @Shorn Thanku after using ```word1[2]==word2[2]``` gives me the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in an elegant manner

```py
a = [['File1', 0, ' Message to check whether all this are same or not'], ['File1', 1, ' Message to check whether all this are same or not'], ['File1', 2, ' Message to check whether all this are same or not'], ['File1', 3, ' Message to check whether all this are same or not'], ['File1', 4, ' Message to check whether all this are same or not']]


# pick the 3rd elem of the first sub list
key_item = a[0][2]

# iterate over the rest of the sub lists
for sub_list in a[1:]:
    if sub_list[2] != key_item:
        print('False')
        break
else:
    print('True')
```

> The else block just after for/while is executed only when the loop is
> NOT terminated by a break statement.

Comment: Sorry I have some change in my question I only want to compare 3rd element of 1st sublist to the rest of other not every sublist

Comment: rest of the first sublist ?

Answer (score 0):

With your current solution, you are going to get a lot of prints of `True` and not a single boolean. Here's a simple version:

```
a = [['File1', 0, ' Message to check whether all this are same or not'], ['File1', 1, ' Message to check whether all this are same or not'], ['File1', 2, ' Message to check whether all this are same or not'], ['File1', 3, ' Message to check whether all this are same or not'], ['File1', 4, ' Message to check whether all this are same or not']]
b = [['File1', 0, ' This is not the same'], ['File1', 1, ' Message to check whether all this are same or not'], ['File1', 2, ' Message to check whether all this are same or not'], ['File1', 3, ' Message to check whether all this are same or not'], ['File1', 4, ' Message to check whether all this are same or not']]

def check_match(full_list):
    original_word = None
    for sublist in full_list:
        if original_word == None:
            original_word = sublist[2]
        elif original_word != sublist[2]:
            return False
    
    return True

print(check_match(a))
print(check_match(b))

#output
True
False
```

If you are looking just to compare the values, you don't have to iterate the list once per item, you can just iterate it through once and check it against the first item. Since the goal is that the items are the same, there is no need to overwrite the check value either. Also, while I put it in a function, a similar effect can be obtained by using `break` and `for-else` statements if you don't want it as a separate function.

Comment: Sorry I have some change in my question I only want to compare 3rd element of 1st sublist to the rest of other not every sublist

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't quite get what you mean by "to the rest of other".

Comment: I only want to compare the 1st sublist element with other not all Like ```a[0][2]==a[1][2] ,a[0][2]==a[2][2] ,a[0][2]==a[3][2] ,a[0][2]==a[4][2]``` not with ```a[1][2]==a[2][2]``` like this ..Hope you understand

Comment: if your desired is the first one (`a[0][2]==a[1][2] ,a[0][2]==a[2][2] ,a[0][2]==a[3][2] ,a[0][2]==a[4][2]`), then both my and @balu's answer does that, albeit in slightly different manners. If you are looking for an output for each one, @balu's answer would be a better fit. If you are looking for an output of all the comparisons together, mine would be a better fit. Neither of our answers compare `a[1][2]` with anything except the original `a[0][2] == a[1][2]`.

Comment: But it prints true for only one time

Comment: Thanku @Shorn for making me understand

Comment: Yes, what mine is doing is sequentially checking `a[0][2]` against the other `a[x][2]` values, where `x` is the other sublist indexes, and as soon as it encounters a non-match, it returns `False` and stops. If you are only trying to check if ALL of the `a[x][2]` values match, then once it finds a non-match there is no need to continue checking. However, if you want a print for each sublist, then the other answer by @balu is a better fit. Mine can be modified to do that easily, but since they have already made a suitable answer you can just refer to theirs.

Comment: In the event that all of them do match, it will just return one `True` value at the end of the checks.

Answer (score -3):

inspired from @balu

```
all([ i[2]==a[0][2] for i in a ])
```